# IntelliJ marking directory as source changes the package name

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ I have a project I've imported from Eclipse. One of my modules has the current source roots:

- src/main/auth with packages (com.business...)
- src/main/authutil with
  packages (com.business...)

When I mark **auth** and **authutil** as Sources Root it alters the package name from **com** to **auth.com** and **authutil.com**.

I've looked in the IML file and it looks correct.

Here it is marked as not source.

[image: Directory marked as not source]

And here it is marked as source.

[image: Directory marked as source]

This is a client's project, so I am not allowed to change the directory structure.

Comment: Is this managed with a POM or with a build.gradle file?

Comment: Neither, shockingly it is an Ant based project. The config is all IntelliJ.

Comment: what're your Intellij and JDK versions?

Comment: IntelliJ 2019.3 Ultimate
SDK 1.8.0_221